# Zoomed color element acting like a transparent element

Tags: javascript

In my color chart, I have set 3 `addEventListener`s for this chart.

1. click on any color(it will transform the viewing scale i,e; zoom the color element for better view)
2. an event for selecting the color by double clicking on it(it will show the color hex code inside a div)
3. an mouseout event (which will retrun the scale size to its normal size)

Everything works fine. The problem is after **3 to 4 time experiment with the color chart small elements behind the zoomed element is visible and if mouse coursor touches them mouseout event triggers which is not desirable**

what's the reason and how can it be fixed?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#colorchart{
  position:fixed;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  left:0px;
  top:200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();" >
<script>
function initialize(){
var table = document.getElementById('colorchart');

table.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

  var target = event.target||event.srcElement;

  if (target.tagName == 'TD') {

    target.style.transform='scale(15,15)';

    target.addEventListener('dblclick',function(event){
    var newTarget=event.target;
    if(newTarget.tagName=='TD'){
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=newTarget.bgColor;

    }},false);

  }
  target.addEventListener('mouseout',function(event){

     var againTarget=event.target;if(againTarget.tagName=='TD'){
     againTarget.style.transform='scale(1,1)';
  }
  },false);
}, false);
}
</script>
<table id="colorchart"  >
 <tr><td bgColor="#FBEFEF"></td><td bgColor="#FBF2EF"></td><td bgColor="#FBF5EF"></td><td bgColor="#FBF8EF"></td><td bgColor="#FBFBEF"></td><td bgColor="#F8FBEF"></td><td bgColor="#F5FBEF"></td><td bgColor="#F2FBEF"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBEF"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBF2"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBF5"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBF8"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBFB"></td><td bgColor="#EFF8FB"></td><td bgColor="#EFF5FB"></td><td bgColor="#EFF2FB"></td><td bgColor="#EFEFFB"></td><td bgColor="#F2EFFB"></td><td bgColor="#F5EFFB"></td><td bgColor="#F8EFFB"></td><td bgColor="#FBEFFB"></td><td bgColor="#FBEFF8"></td><td bgColor="#FBEFF5"></td><td bgColor="#FBEFF2"></td><td bgColor="#FFFFFF"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#F8E0E0"></td><td bgColor="#F8E6E0"></td><td bgColor="#F8ECE0"></td><td bgColor="#F7F2E0"></td><td bgColor="#F7F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#F1F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#ECF8E0"></td><td bgColor="#E6F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8E6"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8EC"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8F1"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8F7"></td><td bgColor="#E0F2F7"></td><td bgColor="#E0ECF8"></td><td bgColor="#E0E6F8"></td><td bgColor="#E0E0F8"></td><td bgColor="#E6E0F8"></td><td bgColor="#ECE0F8"></td><td bgColor="#F2E0F7"></td><td bgColor="#F8E0F7"></td><td bgColor="#F8E0F1"></td><td bgColor="#F8E0EC"></td><td bgColor="#F8E0E6"></td><td bgColor="#FAFAFA"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#F6CECE"></td><td bgColor="#F6D8CE"></td><td bgColor="#F6E3CE"></td><td bgColor="#F5ECCE"></td><td bgColor="#F5F6CE"></td><td bgColor="#ECF6CE"></td><td bgColor="#E3F6CE"></td><td bgColor="#D8F6CE"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6CE"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6D8"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6E3"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6EC"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6F5"></td><td bgColor="#CEECF5"></td><td bgColor="#CEE3F6"></td><td bgColor="#CED8F6"></td><td bgColor="#CECEF6"></td><td bgColor="#D8CEF6"></td><td bgColor="#E3CEF6"></td><td bgColor="#ECCEF5"></td><td bgColor="#F6CEF5"></td><td bgColor="#F6CEEC"></td><td bgColor="#F6CEE3"></td><td bgColor="#F6CED8"></td><td bgColor="#F2F2F2"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#F5A9A9"></td><td bgColor="#F5BCA9"></td><td bgColor="#F5D0A9"></td><td bgColor="#F3E2A9"></td><td bgColor="#F2F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#E1F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#D0F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#BCF5A9"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5BC"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5D0"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5E1"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5F2"></td><td bgColor="#A9E2F3"></td><td bgColor="#A9D0F5"></td><td bgColor="#A9BCF5"></td><td bgColor="#A9A9F5"></td><td bgColor="#BCA9F5"></td><td bgColor="#D0A9F5"></td><td bgColor="#E2A9F3"></td><td bgColor="#F5A9F2"></td><td bgColor="#F5A9E1"></td><td bgColor="#F5A9D0"></td><td bgColor="#F5A9BC"></td><td bgColor="#E6E6E6"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#F78181"></td><td bgColor="#F79F81"></td><td bgColor="#F7BE81"></td><td bgColor="#F5DA81"></td><td bgColor="#F3F781"></td><td bgColor="#D8F781"></td><td bgColor="#BEF781"></td><td bgColor="#9FF781"></td><td bgColor="#81F781"></td><td bgColor="#81F79F"></td><td bgColor="#81F7BE"></td><td bgColor="#81F7D8"></td><td bgColor="#81F7F3"></td><td bgColor="#81DAF5"></td><td bgColor="#81BEF7"></td><td bgColor="#819FF7"></td><td bgColor="#8181F7"></td><td bgColor="#9F81F7"></td><td bgColor="#BE81F7"></td><td bgColor="#DA81F5"></td><td bgColor="#F781F3"></td><td bgColor="#F781D8"></td><td bgColor="#F781BE"></td><td bgColor="#F7819F"></td><td bgColor="#D8D8D8"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#FA5858"></td><td bgColor="#FA8258"></td><td bgColor="#FAAC58"></td><td bgColor="#F7D358"></td><td bgColor="#F4FA58"></td><td bgColor="#D0FA58"></td><td bgColor="#ACFA58"></td><td bgColor="#82FA58"></td><td bgColor="#58FA58"></td><td bgColor="#58FA82"></td><td bgColor="#58FAAC"></td><td bgColor="#58FAD0"></td><td bgColor="#58FAF4"></td><td bgColor="#58D3F7"></td><td bgColor="#58ACFA"></td><td bgColor="#5882FA"></td><td bgColor="#5858FA"></td><td bgColor="#8258FA"></td><td bgColor="#AC58FA"></td><td bgColor="#D358F7"></td><td bgColor="#FA58F4"></td><td bgColor="#FA58D0"></td><td bgColor="#FA58AC"></td><td bgColor="#FA5882"></td><td bgColor="#BDBDBD"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#FE2E2E"></td><td bgColor="#FE642E"></td><td bgColor="#FE9A2E"></td><td bgColor="#FACC2E"></td><td bgColor="#F7FE2E"></td><td bgColor="#C8FE2E"></td><td bgColor="#9AFE2E"></td><td bgColor="#64FE2E"></td><td bgColor="#2EFE2E"></td><td bgColor="#2EFE64"></td><td bgColor="#2EFE9A"></td><td bgColor="#2EFEC8"></td><td bgColor="#2EFEF7"></td><td bgColor="#2ECCFA"></td><td bgColor="#2E9AFE"></td><td bgColor="#2E64FE"></td><td bgColor="#2E2EFE"></td><td bgColor="#642EFE"></td><td bgColor="#9A2EFE"></td><td bgColor="#CC2EFA"></td><td bgColor="#FE2EF7"></td><td bgColor="#FE2EC8"></td><td bgColor="#FE2E9A"></td><td bgColor="#FE2E64"></td><td bgColor="#A4A4A4"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#FF0000"></td><td bgColor="#FF4000"></td><td bgColor="#FF8000"></td><td bgColor="#FFBF00"></td><td bgColor="#FFFF00"></td><td bgColor="#BFFF00"></td><td bgColor="#80FF00"></td><td bgColor="#40FF00"></td><td bgColor="#00FF00"></td><td bgColor="#00FF40"></td><td bgColor="#00FF80"></td><td bgColor="#00FFBF"></td><td bgColor="#00FFFF"></td><td bgColor="#00BFFF"></td><td bgColor="#0080FF"></td><td bgColor="#0040FF"></td><td bgColor="#0000FF"></td><td bgColor="#4000FF"></td><td bgColor="#8000FF"></td><td bgColor="#BF00FF"></td><td bgColor="#FF00FF"></td><td bgColor="#FF00BF"></td><td bgColor="#FF0080"></td><td bgColor="#FF0040"></td><td bgColor="#848484"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#DF0101"></td><td bgColor="#DF3A01"></td><td bgColor="#DF7401"></td><td bgColor="#DBA901"></td><td bgColor="#D7DF01"></td><td bgColor="#A5DF00"></td><td bgColor="#74DF00"></td><td bgColor="#3ADF00"></td><td bgColor="#01DF01"></td><td bgColor="#01DF3A"></td><td bgColor="#01DF74"></td><td bgColor="#01DFA5"></td><td bgColor="#01DFD7"></td><td bgColor="#01A9DB"></td><td bgColor="#0174DF"></td><td bgColor="#013ADF"></td><td bgColor="#0101DF"></td><td bgColor="#3A01DF"></td><td bgColor="#7401DF"></td><td bgColor="#A901DB"></td><td bgColor="#DF01D7"></td><td bgColor="#DF01A5"></td><td bgColor="#DF0174"></td><td bgColor="#DF013A"></td><td bgColor="#6E6E6E"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#B40404"></td><td bgColor="#B43104"></td><td bgColor="#B45F04"></td><td bgColor="#B18904"></td><td bgColor="#AEB404"></td><td bgColor="#86B404"></td><td bgColor="#5FB404"></td><td bgColor="#31B404"></td><td bgColor="#04B404"></td><td bgColor="#04B431"></td><td bgColor="#04B45F"></td><td bgColor="#04B486"></td><td bgColor="#04B4AE"></td><td bgColor="#0489B1"></td><td bgColor="#045FB4"></td><td bgColor="#0431B4"></td><td bgColor="#0404B4"></td><td bgColor="#3104B4"></td><td bgColor="#5F04B4"></td><td bgColor="#8904B1"></td><td bgColor="#B404AE"></td><td bgColor="#B40486"></td><td bgColor="#B4045F"></td><td bgColor="#B40431"></td><td bgColor="#585858"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#8A0808"></td><td bgColor="#8A2908"></td><td bgColor="#8A4B08"></td><td bgColor="#886A08"></td><td bgColor="#868A08"></td><td bgColor="#688A08"></td><td bgColor="#4B8A08"></td><td bgColor="#298A08"></td><td bgColor="#088A08"></td><td bgColor="#088A29"></td><td bgColor="#088A4B"></td><td bgColor="#088A68"></td><td bgColor="#088A85"></td><td bgColor="#086A87"></td><td bgColor="#084B8A"></td><td bgColor="#08298A"></td><td bgColor="#08088A"></td><td bgColor="#29088A"></td><td bgColor="#4B088A"></td><td bgColor="#6A0888"></td><td bgColor="#8A0886"></td><td bgColor="#8A0868"></td><td bgColor="#8A084B"></td><td bgColor="#8A0829"></td><td bgColor="#424242"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#610B0B"></td><td bgColor="#61210B"></td><td bgColor="#61380B"></td><td bgColor="#5F4C0B"></td><td bgColor="#5E610B"></td><td bgColor="#4B610B"></td><td bgColor="#38610B"></td><td bgColor="#21610B"></td><td bgColor="#0B610B"></td><td bgColor="#0B6121"></td><td bgColor="#0B6138"></td><td bgColor="#0B614B"></td><td bgColor="#0B615E"></td><td bgColor="#0B4C5F"></td><td bgColor="#0B3861"></td><td bgColor="#0B2161"></td><td bgColor="#0B0B61"></td><td bgColor="#210B61"></td><td bgColor="#380B61"></td><td bgColor="#4C0B5F"></td><td bgColor="#610B5E"></td><td bgColor="#610B4B"></td><td bgColor="#610B38"></td><td bgColor="#610B21"></td><td bgColor="#2E2E2E"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#3B0B0B"></td><td bgColor="#3B170B"></td><td bgColor="#3B240B"></td><td bgColor="#3A2F0B"></td><td bgColor="#393B0B"></td><td bgColor="#2E3B0B"></td><td bgColor="#243B0B"></td><td bgColor="#173B0B"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B0B"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B17"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B24"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B2E"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B39"></td><td bgColor="#0B2F3A"></td><td bgColor="#0B243B"></td><td bgColor="#0B173B"></td><td bgColor="#0B0B3B"></td><td bgColor="#170B3B"></td><td bgColor="#240B3B"></td><td bgColor="#2F0B3A"></td><td bgColor="#3B0B39"></td><td bgColor="#3B0B2E"></td><td bgColor="#3B0B24"></td><td bgColor="#3B0B17"></td><td bgColor="#1C1C1C"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#2A0A0A"></td><td bgColor="#2A120A"></td><td bgColor="#2A1B0A"></td><td bgColor="#29220A"></td><td bgColor="#292A0A"></td><td bgColor="#222A0A"></td><td bgColor="#1B2A0A"></td><td bgColor="#122A0A"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A0A"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A12"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A1B"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A22"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A29"></td><td bgColor="#0A2229"></td><td bgColor="#0A1B2A"></td><td bgColor="#0A122A"></td><td bgColor="#0A0A2A"></td><td bgColor="#120A2A"></td><td bgColor="#1B0A2A"></td><td bgColor="#220A29"></td><td bgColor="#2A0A29"></td><td bgColor="#2A0A22"></td><td bgColor="#2A0A1B"></td><td bgColor="#2A0A12"></td><td bgColor="#151515"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#190707"></td><td bgColor="#190B07"></td><td bgColor="#191007"></td><td bgColor="#181407"></td><td bgColor="#181907"></td><td bgColor="#141907"></td><td bgColor="#101907"></td><td bgColor="#0B1907"></td><td bgColor="#071907"></td><td bgColor="#07190B"></td><td bgColor="#071910"></td><td bgColor="#071914"></td><td bgColor="#071918"></td><td bgColor="#071418"></td><td bgColor="#071019"></td><td bgColor="#070B19"></td><td bgColor="#070719"></td><td bgColor="#0B0719"></td><td bgColor="#100719"></td><td bgColor="#140718"></td><td bgColor="#190718"></td><td bgColor="#190714"></td><td bgColor="#190710"></td><td bgColor="#19070B"></td><td bgColor="#000000"></td></tr>
</table>
get color code<span style="color:blue;">(double click on your color):</span><div id="mydiv" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;color:red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

pic is added.you can see that small divs from behind pops up through the zoomed element

[image]

Comment: I ran it, and it seems to be fine. Maybe you can post an image of what you're seeing that i'm probably not?

Comment: woah, i didnt get that. What browser are you using?

Comment: i am using firefox.haven't tested opera yet.

Comment: let me try it in firefox

Comment: Ok, its definitely a FireFox Issue, chrome didnt give me that problem. let me see if i can find a workaround and if so, Ill post it as an answer.

Comment: another problem i found that in opera scale remains the same.but color code shows when i double clicked on the original element.why browsers acting so wired .i am confused!!!!!!

Comment: HEres what I've found. Not enough to create a viable answer but:  At `target.style.transform='scale(15,15)';` the box appears. @user3138436

Comment: When set back to `target.style.transform='scale(1,1)';` it disappears.

Comment: Alright, this is kinda cheating but whatever. Since DOM styles are COMPLETELY DIFFERENT from CSS styles, try messing with opacity till you get it the way you want?

Comment: Wait a minute, that may be why it isn't working! DOM Styles and CSS styles are different. -_- (really developers?)

Comment: so how it can be fixed?

Comment: Let me do some more testing,to see if remove/replace CSS attributes with DOM Attributes

Comment: set a zIndex value for both scale increase and decrease works fine for firefox.but chrome and opera remains the same :\

Comment: I didn't have any issues in chrome, Haven't tried opera...